# How to seach for JSON data in GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, dataview

I want to search in a `GridView` for any given text. I have found the code that I have written in the TextChanged Event.

But it doesn't seem to work at all.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    jsonData = wc.DownloadString("http://10.10.62.104/xmoads/3.0/installationsex?_token=70AB896E-D8A3-4789-9F31-5588C93F3C5F&format=json");
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonResult>>(jsonData);
    constringview.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    constringview.DataSource = result;
}

private void textSoeg_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (constringview.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = 
        string.Format("Navn LIKE '%{0}%'", textSoeg.Text);
}
```

Doing some research, I've found a lot which includes SQL databases and how to search in those; however, that's not what I need.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong, or is it even possible?

The data in the gridview is shown correctly:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRSuf.png)

Comment: Any one that can help me? =)

Comment: What is the issue you're actually getting? I just made a brand new project, populated a new GridView and the `TextChanged` event worked fine!

Comment: I've done it when I had the data in my own MS SQL database.. But now I get the data via the json format, so now I can't do the same I did when I had the SQL database (Select statement).

And the above code are not working.

But I can see it has something to do with the DataTable stuff

Comment: Is your GridView even being populated?

Comment: I can see it in the program when builded, and its filled correctly with the json data specified in the result variable.

I have added a screenshot.